# How can i get all users in a specific location in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get all Facebook users centered around 12.9667° N, 77.5667°E. 
How can I do this?

I have tried the following query. But the Center and distance parameter don't seem to be working .

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user&center=12.9667,77.5667&distance=1000

I still get Mark Zuckerberg in the results, even though he is no where close to the specified Lat-Long.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `center` and `distance` field don't apply to the `user` object because the `current_location` field is not publicly available through the API. So, they are just ignored.

> `user_location` or `friends_location` permissions to view:
>   `current_location`
>
> Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Comment: If that is the case, how can I find all users in a particular location through Facebook Graph API? I want something Equivalent to typing "All people staying in California" in graph search?

Comment: You can't. The Facebook API, for privacy reason, is not open to search (otherwise than by their name) for people who are not your friends.